# Is it possible to start an OAuth 2 flow on the submission of a Google Form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-oauth

I am writing a script that requires an API call be sent to a service that requires OAuth 2.0 authentication.

The code looks as follows, using the [apps-script-oauth2](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) library.

However, the OAuth 2.0 flow never starts, and the function fails on the line `const accessToken = service.getAccessToken()`
with an error message `Error: Access not granted or expired. (line 454, file "Service")`. It does not provide information as to what went wrong.

```
function run() {
  let accessToken = initService()
  // do tasks requiring access token ... 
}

/*
 * Create and authorize the service. 
 */ 
function initService() {
  var service = getService(SERVICE_NAME);
  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        'Reopen the sidebar when the authorization is complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    FormApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);
  }
    
  const accessToken = service.getAccessToken() 
  return accessToken
}

/*
 * Callback function for OAuth2 authorization.  
 */ 
function authCallback(request) {
  let service = getService(SERVICE_NAME);
  let isAuthorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}

/** 
  * Create a new service with the given name. 
  */ 
function getService(name) {
  return OAuth2.createService(name)
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl(AUTHORIZATION_URL)
      .setTokenUrl(TOKEN_URL)
      .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
      .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
      .setParam('login_hint', Session.getActiveUser().getEmail())
      .setParam('approval_prompt', 'auto');
}
```

Comment: It works for me with service account credentials if you are interested in thsi workflow as a workaround! Very important: set scopes!